# Issue deploying ASP.NET application, having MSAL and OWIN middleware

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, owin, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application in which, I have used Microsoft Authentication layer and custom OWIN middleware, this application is to integrate Microsoft Office Unified API's. All works great while the app is in development mode and development server.

But when it is deployed on local IIS or any other IIS server, it throws an error. The issue is when i try to log in after successfully crossing OWIN authentication. The next step is loading of API in async way. I face this issue while the code attempts to access: GetMyFilesAndFolders and GetUsers API.
There comes and error which states:

> Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied.

It tried a lot but no luck why this error is coming.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

You can get one reference https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: With ample of debug and detect we found that, this issue is due to the license of lingo 3g, we have placed it in web root directory as mentioned in this documentation (https://get.carrotsearch.com/lingo3g/manual/#section.license) from lingo3G with no luck and still the issue is coming up as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved as this was in the assembly code itself and not the issue of custom code. It has been resolved in the new Version of Carrot Search lingo 3G.